# Algorithm to find connected tiles (percolation)

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, graph, javafx

I wrote a little program in JavaFX which displays a path of neighbouring open tiles going from top to bottom. It should simulate a percolation.

The algorithm iterates through the whole grid (every tile) populating a list with tiles that have a continuous connection to the top. It all works somewhat. My concern however is that it probably is highly inefficient and I don't really know how to improve said efficiency as we didn't learn anything of that sort in my school.

`burnt` is just another `ArrayList` initialised as a member variable.

[GitHub link](https://github.com/Equiphract/Percolation/tree/e3c0879f155b4844e25ef5141a4b32683932d643)

```
public void searchCluster(Grid grid){
    Node[][] array = grid.getNodeArray();
    ArrayList<Node> tmpBurnt = new ArrayList();
    LinkedList<Node> tmpSave = new LinkedList();
    Node left;
    Node right;
    Node below;

    for(Node n : array[0]){
        if(n.isSet()){
            tmpBurnt.add(n);
        }
    }

    for(;;){
        if(tmpBurnt.isEmpty()){
            return;
        }
        for(Node n : tmpBurnt){
            //-----check left--------
            if(n.getX() > 0){
                left = array[n.getY()][n.getX() - 1];
                if(left.isSet() && !tmpBurnt.contains(left) && !this.burnt.contains(left)){
                    tmpSave.add(left);
                }
            }
            //-----check right--------
            if(n.getX() < array[n.getY()].length - 1){
                right = array[n.getY()][n.getX() + 1];
                if(right.isSet() && !tmpBurnt.contains(right) && !this.burnt.contains(right)){
                    tmpSave.add(right);
                }
            }
            //-----check below--------
            if(n.getY() < array.length - 1){
                below = array[n.getY() + 1][n.getX()];
                if(below.isSet() && !tmpBurnt.contains(below) && !this.burnt.contains(below)){
                    tmpSave.add(below);
                }
            }
        }
        for(Node n : tmpBurnt){
            this.burnt.add(n);
        }
        tmpBurnt.clear();
        for(Node n : tmpSave){
            tmpBurnt.add(n);
        }
        tmpSave.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you scan *left* and *right* but not *up* and *down*?

Comment: @MartinFrank   I actually do scan downwards, see the "check below" comment. I didn't scan upwards at the time which you correctly stated was a mistake.